# angular application with version 7 is not running

Tags: angular, angular5, angular7

I upgraded my running angular application from version 5 to 7 now. since, the upgrade. I am getting this error.[image: tsickle error]

I tried to resolve with upgrading and downgrading the version of tsickle, as @angular/core depends on it. but, still I am getting the same error. But, still I didn't find any success.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Debug the code to figure out where the exception is occurring. Your code is calling `reverse` on an instance that does not have a value assigned. Set break points or set your browser to stop on exceptions.

Comment: Unhandled Promise rejection: Unable to get property 'reverse' of undefined or null reference ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: Unable to get property 'reverse' of undefined or null reference TypeError: Unable to get property 'reverse' of undefined or null reference

this error in vendor.js on function strategyIndex.

Comment: This error is coming through tsickle library

Comment: Fairly sure angular 7 does not need tsickle. Uninstall it manualy and try again. I have an angular 7 project and there is no sign of it here.

Comment: It has a peer dependency for angular core, when I updated from 5 to 7 I got to know about this